# Typedef for a pointer to a cv- and/or ref-qualified member function

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, c++14, pointer-to-member

```
struct foo {
    void bar(int&&) && { }
};

template<class T>
using bar_t = void (std::decay_t<T>::*)(int&&) /* add && if T is an rvalue reference */;

int main()
{
    using other_t = void (foo::*)(int&&) &&;
    static_assert(std::is_same<bar_t<foo&&>, other_t>::value, "not the same");

    return 0;
}
```

I want that

- `bar_t<T>` yields `void (foo::*)(int&&)` if `T = foo`
- `bar_t<T>` yields `void (foo::*)(int&&) const` if `T = foo const`
- `bar_t<T>` yields `void (foo::*)(int&&) &` if `T = foo&`
- `bar_t<T>` yields `void (foo::*)(int&&) const&` if `T = foo const&`

and so on. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What's the use case for this?

Comment: Distributing CV qualifiers the same way you can distribute lvalue/rvalue with perfect forwarding. It's not correct in general to assume CV- and LR-invariance, but providing it is really valuable, especially if it's a property you can define as a trait. You won't have to write separate logic for each variant - hence 'invariance' - and you'll be able to reason inductively about compositions of these.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

```
template <typename, typename T> struct add {using type = T;};
template <typename F, typename C, typename R, typename... Args>
struct add<F const, R (C::*)(Args...)> {using type = R (C::*)(Args...) const;};

template <typename F, typename C, typename R, typename... Args>
struct add<F&, R (C::*)(Args...)> :
  std::conditional<std::is_const<F>{}, R (C::*)(Args...) const&,
                                       R (C::*)(Args...) &> {};
template <typename F, typename C, typename R, typename... Args>
struct add<F&&, R (C::*)(Args...)> :
  std::conditional<std::is_const<F>{}, R (C::*)(Args...) const&&,
                                       R (C::*)(Args...) &&> {};
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae0daa74e5c52995). Note that the underlying type of `F` is ignored.

Comment: ...need...more...partial...specializations... ;)

Comment: @T.C. "should". I'm not covering pointers to variadic member functions at 11pm. ;)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function > 'Possible Implementation' shows how ugly this could get. On the other hand, the qualifiers and subjects being qualified are orthogonal, and the corresponding `std::add_const` can automate what you're already doing manually. It might be worth it to future-proof us against C++23's 'Rule of 16777215'. :)